# Woocommerce Single Product Summary - move price

Tags: woocommerce

In Woocommerce, I would like to move the price from just above the add to cart button to right underneath the title and reviews. I have tried re prioritizing the `woocommerce_template_single_price`, but it seems to be part of the             `woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart` instead.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: I forgot to change the image description. It just shows what I would like to move and where

Comment: It seems to me that your theme already has some price placement modification cos by default on single product page you can find price under product title https://prnt.sc/kz2tvv